# Function breaks all code that come after it

Tags: python, function

I've started working on a small game. I've created a function that breaks all the code that follows it. Here's the full function:

```
def printBoard(currentBoard):
#Prints out the game board
for x in range(5):
    #prints out 50 character line x
    print (' '.join(str(currentBoard[x*50:(x+1)*50]))
```

although it still works with just this:

```
def printBoard(currentBoard):
    print (' '.join(str(currentBoard[x*50:(x+1)*50]))
```

even things like:

```
print("Hello")
```

won't work after it. I've tried switching around variable names and such but the error the error still remains.

Comment: All the code in your `printBoard` function should be indented one level.

Comment: You should really give us the traceback of the exceptions you're seeing. Without that, we can only guess what error is cropping up and where it's happening.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you are missing a closing ")"

Answer (score -1):

Your indentation is wrong, change the function to this:

```
def printBoard(currentBoard):
    #Prints out the game board
    for x in range(5):
        #prints out 50 character line x
        print (' '.join(str(currentBoard[x*50:(x+1)*50]))
```

Comment: I didn't DV, but I don't think that is the case (although it is a minor part of the problem).